# failed to make a row of clickable buttons in UIScrollView with paging enabled

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, hittest

I am trying to make a row of buttons which can be scrolled horizontally. Like the news items in a feed in the Pulse News Reader app.
I've successful made enabled paging on UIScrollView with the page size same as the width of a button. i.e. 3 buttons on the screen at once,  | 1 | 2 | 3 | , if I swipe left, it becomes | 2 | 3 | 4 |.
I made this possible by using a method I founded here in stackoverflow:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) { 
        return scrollView;
    }
   return nil;}
```

by turning the clipsToBounds to NO in the UIScrollView containing the row of buttons and then overlaying another view on top of it for getting the swipe gestures.
It moves and snap to position perfectly!

But now the biggest problem is that I can't click the buttons except the one inside the bound! What should I do to make those button clickable? 
I thought I can get the touch events and pass it to the UIScrollView containing those buttons, but I found that once the above method is used, I can't get any touchesBegan, touchesEnd, touchesMoved and touchesCancelled response to me.I've been finding way out for days painfully, please point me into a correct direction. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I'm confused - I've done this before without using a new view to catch gestures - it should just work with paging set to YES. Can you post some more code so we can see how you've set up your scrollview?

Comment: deanWombourne, my situation is like this: using pulse news reader app as an example, when you swipe the row, it snaps(the paging effect) with the width of each square. I know in order to make it snap to the width of a square, I need to set the bound to the width of the square. but after the bound is set, it clips all the thing out of the bound, so I set the clipToBounds to NO so that the next few squares are shown on the screen. When I tried to swipe on the row at this moment, I found that only swipes inside the bound is detected, swipes on the contents that shown up due to clipToBounds=NO

Comment: is not responding, so to expand the swipe detecting area, I overlay another invisible view on the row which with the width of the screen to get all the swipes and passes to the scrollview below. Now I swipe anywhere on the row, it moves. But the problem left is, I can't click any of the buttons on the row because the top view I used get the swipes isn't passing any taps to the scrollview, the button inside the bounds doesn't response, not to say the buttons outside the clipping view.